# Leaflet-Omnivore make external file.geojson available to javascript variable

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, turfjs

I'm using the [Omnivore extension](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore) to load my GeoJSON files into a Mapbox/ Leaflet map.  Later, I'm using [Turf.js](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf) on this data.

I'm loading the external GeoJSON file to the map as a customLayer, but having trouble making the GeoJSON data available in the variable `pts` for use later.

```html
var polyLayer = L.geoJson(null, {
    style: function(feature) {
        return { color: '#f00', weight: 1, opacity: 0.9
  };
    }
}).addTo(map);

var polys = omnivore.geojson('polys.geojson', null, polyLayer);


var ptsLayer = L.geoJson(null, {
 onEachFeature: labelEachFeature, 
 pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
  return L.circleMarker(latlng, style(feature))
 ;}
});

var pts = omnivore.geojson('pts.geojson', null, ptsLayer);

polyLayer.on('mouseover', function(e) {
 var matchingPoints = turf.featurecollection([])
 matchingPoints.features = pts.features.filter(function(pt) {
   if(pt.properties.servesbldg === e.layer.feature.properties.bldg_no) return true
 })

 ptsLayer.setGeoJSON(matchingPoints);
});


function getPoints(building, pts) {
  var matchingPoints = turf.featurecollection([])
  matchingPoints.features = pts.features.filter(function(pt) {
 if(pt.properties.servesbldg === building.properties.bldg_no) return true
  })
  return matchingPoints
}
```

[Here's a GIST of what I've got](http://bl.ocks.org/pdbartsch/ac5fdd2f0c09e8ff3a4d) including the GeoJSON files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using omnivore to grab the pts layer... Why not declare a pts variable, use jQuery.getJSON to grab pts.geojson and assign that response  to the pts variable, then call L.geoJson(pts).addTo(map). Then you have the layer added, and you have the original geojson structure available for use in other places, like you need.

Comment: Thanks @snkashis.  I'll give that a try.  My end goal is to have a template that I can use for multiple projects, some using formats other than GeoJSON, so wanted to keep my options open.  I'll try your suggestion for now though.  Thanks.

Comment: Great, let us know if it gets the job done as you need.

Comment: snkashis- that ended up working, although I now have .getJSON nested in another call to .getJSON.   It's a little akward and there's probably a better way than what I ended up with, but it works for now. Thanks for your help.  If you're interested, this is what I ended up with: http://bl.ocks.org/pdbartsch/ac5fdd2f0c09e8ff3a4d

Comment: Well I suppose one thing you could do to clean things up a bit would be to use a async lib like Bluebird or RSVP to get rid of the nesting and grab all the JSON you need inside a promise.

Comment: I'll look into those libraries. Thanks again!

Comment: Cool. I recommend Bluebird.